# SQLi Insert into table

Tags: php

when i generate below code, i got an error:
Notice: Undefined index: materialcode_1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmg-logistics\make_order.php on line 47

```
//insert into database-Line Item Data
$line_item = '';
$more = TRUE;
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
      if((isset($_POST['lineitem_'.$i])) && ($_POST['lineitem_'.$i] !="")){
        $line_item = $_POST['lineitem_'.$i];
        $materialcode = $_POST['materialcode_'.$i];
        $query_line_item = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_item (order_number, item, material) values ('$add_nr', '$line_item', 
        '$materialcode')";
        $result_line_item = mysqli_query($con, $query_line_item);
        }else
        {
            $more = FALSE;
        }
}
```

please help!

Comment: Which line is line 47?

Comment: $_POST['materialcode_'.$i];

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST)` and check what you actually have in your POST data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a condition to check whether this exists:

```
$_POST['materialcode_'.$i];
```

For example:

```
//insert into database-Line Item Data
$line_item = '';
$more = TRUE;
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
      if((isset($_POST['lineitem_'.$i])) && ($_POST['lineitem_'.$i] !="") && (isset($_POST['materialcode_'.$i])) && ($_POST['materialcode_'.$i] !="") ){
        $line_item = $_POST['lineitem_'.$i];
        $materialcode = $_POST['materialcode_'.$i];
        $query_line_item = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_item (order_number, item, material) values ('$add_nr', '$line_item', 
        '$materialcode')";
        $result_line_item = mysqli_query($con, $query_line_item);
        }else
        {
            $more = FALSE;
        }
}
```

What the error message says is that `$_POST['materialcode_1']` is  not existing in the data you got!

Comment: php send only 2nd record to database, i lost first record. what's wrong with it?

Comment: Check your form(where the data is being filled and send to the php page  for insertion). My guess is that `lineitem_1` or `materialcode_1` might be missing in it!

Comment: all fields are complete with data. lineitem_1 & materialcode_1 is the same row. when i click on adding button, lineitem_1 & materialcode_1 are created a new line. if i have two records, php send record of new line and i don't see first line in table.

Comment: @Ratana, are you naming each `lineitem_*` and `materialcode_*` from 0 to 4 or 1 to 5. Because in your loop, the iteration starts from 0 and goes till 4. Anyway, I think I didn't got the above comment of yours. One thing you can do is, put this line `var_dump($_POST);`  just before that loop and see whether all data is submitted to your PHP page!